# CDK Pipelines UpdatePipeline Stage Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I tried to deploy CloudFormation file synthed from CDK project. CodePipeline is deployed using CDK Pipelines. But it fails at the UpdatePipeline stage. The role `cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-608983964447-ap-southeast-1` is available. And `WhitespaceApp-CdkPipelineUpdatePipelineSelfMutatio-5L0H9BL407WF` does have rights to assume role `cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-608983964447-ap-southeast-1`. Not sure why `arn:aws:sts::608983964447:assumed-role/WhitespaceApp-CdkPipelineUpdatePipelineSelfMutatio-5L0H9BL407WF/AWSCodeBuild-cd23f13d-0319-4d13-b338-1fc8d68d8917` failed to assume same role.

```
--app points to a cloud assembly, so we bypass synth
109 WhitespaceApp: deploying...
110 Retrieved account ID 608983964447 from disk cache
111 Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::608983964447:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-608983964447-ap-southeast-1'.
112 Assuming role failed: User: arn:aws:sts::608983964447:assumed-role/WhitespaceApp-CdkPipelineUpdatePipelineSelfMutatio-5L0H9BL407WF/AWSCodeBuild-cd23f13d-0319-4d13-b338-1fc8d68d8917 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::608983964447:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-608983964447-ap-southeast-1
113 Could not assume role in target account using current credentials User: arn:aws:sts::608983964447:assumed-role/WhitespaceApp-CdkPipelineUpdatePipelineSelfMutatio-5L0H9BL407WF/AWSCodeBuild-cd23f13d-0319-4d13-b338-1fc8d68d8917 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::608983964447:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-608983964447-ap-southeast-1 . Please make sure that this role exists in the account. If it doesn't exist, (re)-bootstrap the environment with the right '--trust', using the latest version of the CDK CLI.
114 current credentials could not be used to assume 'arn:aws:iam::608983964447:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-608983964447-ap-southeast-1', but are for the right account. Proceeding anyway.
115 Waiting for stack CDKToolkit to finish creating or updating...
116 Call failed: getParameter({"Name":"/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version"}) => User: arn:aws:sts::608983964447:assumed-role/WhitespaceApp-CdkPipelineUpdatePipelineSelfMutatio-5L0H9BL407WF/AWSCodeBuild-cd23f13d-0319-4d13-b338-1fc8d68d8917 is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:ap-southeast-1:608983964447:parameter/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version (code=AccessDeniedException)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes for these things it helps to re-bootstrap ALL the relevant regions and accounts with the correct --trust account. Sometimes one region has an old bootstrap version and is missing some permissions. Sometimes you're really unlucky and it's a service control policy blocking you. Or someone manually altered the role.

Comment: Thank you, LRutten. Re-bootstrap the environment solve the problem.